# Why do each of these cylindrical triple integrals evaluate differently?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

The problem in question is thus:
Find the volume cut out of the sphere of a radius $a$ centered at the origin by the polar curve $r = a\cos\theta$. I attempted to solve the problem using this cylindrical triple integral, taking advantage of $x$-axis symmetry.
$$
2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{a\cos\theta}\int_{-\sqrt{a^2 - r^2}}^{\sqrt{a^2 - r^2}}r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta = \frac{2\pi a^3}{3} - \frac{8a^3}{9}
$$
However, when this, similar integral is evaluated (which in my mind should yield the same results as the first one), the answer is different as the last term cancels out.
$$
\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^{a\cos\theta}\int_{-\sqrt{a^2 - r^2}}^{\sqrt{a^2 - r^2}} r \, dz\,dr\,d\theta = \frac{2\pi a^3}{3}
$$
Which one of these answers is correct and why is the other one wrong? I understand that it has something to do with the theta integral, but I have no idea where my error is in assuming that these two triple integrals should produce identical results.

Thanks! This is my first time on the Math Stack Exchange so let me know if there is anything else I can do to improve the nature of my question.

THANK YOU ALL!!! Many wonderful explanations below, have a great day everyone!

Comment: It's not clear what is meant by the "volume cut out ... by the polar curve". How does a 2-D curve cut out a volume from the sphere?

Comment: $2\pi a^3/3$ is the volume of the hemisphere so it is clear that the second answer is wrong. But the integral itself seems to be correct so it is likely that you made some calculation error.

Comment: I'm guessing this "polar curve" is intended to be actually a cylinder.

Comment: @Chrystomath essentially the problem is asking for a cylinder to be cut of of the sphere!

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Is it possible that I could send you the work for both and you could take a look at it? I'm not sure how to upload a pdf in the Math Stack Exchange.

Comment: You can take a screenshot and put the link.

Comment: The outer integral is with respect to $\theta$ and the function of $\theta$ that is being integrated depends on $\theta$ only through $\cos\theta,$ so if you integrate it over an interval symmetric about $0,$ you should get twice as much as if you integrate it from $0$ to one of those endpoints. Thus certainly something is wrong in what is written in the current version of this question.

Comment: I get the correct answer on Wolfram

Comment: You may have some calculation mistake

Comment: @MathLover Which is...?

Comment: of course the first one :)

Comment: I was trying on the free version and it was timing out so I put $a = 1$. I got $2 \times 0.602755$ from the first and with the second, $1.20551$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/772929722095108127/775568319771443200/image0.jpg WORK TO THE SECOND

Comment: @ShubhamJohri https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/772929722095108127/775759060682276954/Stack1.png WORK TO THE FIRST

Comment: @MichaelScutari Yup, you have forgotten to take the modulus around $a\sin\theta$. Look at my edited answer

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Your answer is perfect! Not sure how I can give the right answer thing to two people, but you were spot on amazingly helpful!

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
& 2\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{a\cos\theta}\int_{-\sqrt{a^2 - r^2}}^{\sqrt{a^2 - r^2}}r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta \\ {} \\
= {} & 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{a\cos\theta} \sqrt{a^2-r^2} (2r \, dr)\,d\theta \\ {} \\
= {} & 2\int_0^{\pi/2} \int^a_{a\sin\theta} \sqrt u \, du \, d\theta 
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @MichaelScutari No biggy. It is ultimately your doubt that has to get resolved. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The working is not shown, so the following is conjecture on how the first and second integrals were worked out.

$$I(\theta)=\int_0^{a\cos\theta}\int_{-\sqrt{a^2-r^2}}^{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}}r\, dz\,dr=\int_0^{a\cos\theta}2r\sqrt{a^2-r^2}\,dr=\frac{4}{3}\Big[(a^2-r^2)^{3/2}\Big]_0^{a\cos\theta}=\frac{4a^3}{3}(\sin^3\theta-1)$$

Then $2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^3\theta\,d\theta=\frac{4}{3},\qquad\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin^3\theta\,d\theta=0$ give out different answers.

The problem occurs because the last expression $\sin^3\theta-1$ is not correct. Substituting $\cos\theta$ into $(1-r^2)^{3/2}$ gives $(\sin^2\theta)^{3/2}=|\sin\theta|^3$ which is always non-negative.

Comment: Why is it that although you carefully separate $dr$ by a thin space from what follows it, but not from what precedes it?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for editing it out. Sorry, I'm not a perfectionist when it comes to writing formulas on SE. I'm on to the next question.

Answer (score 1):

$2\pi a^3/3$ is the volume of the hemisphere so it is clear that the second *answer* is
wrong. But the integral itself seems to be correct since $2\int_0^{\pi/2}f(\cos\theta)\,d\theta=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} f(\cos\theta)\,d\theta$ due to the evenness of $\cos\theta$ so it is likely that you made some calculation error.

In fact it seems [symbolab is making the same error](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint_%7B-%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B2%7D%7D%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B2%7D%7D%20%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7Ba%20%5Ccos%5Ctheta%7D%20%5Cint_%7B-%5Csqrt%7Ba%5E%7B2%7D-r%5E%7B2%7D%7D%7D%5E%7B%5Csqrt%7Ba%5E2-r%5E2%7D%7D%20r%20dz%20dr%20d%5Ctheta). The second integral is$$2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{a\cos\theta}r\sqrt{a^2-r^2} \, dr~d\theta=-\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_{a^2}^{a^2\sin^2\theta}\sqrt m\,dm~d\theta$$where $m=a^2-r^2$. This gives$$V=-\frac23\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}(\color{red}|a\sin\theta\color{red}|^3-|a|^3)\,d\theta$$So you have probability forgotten to take the modulus and landed at the answer of $2\pi a^3/3$.

Comment: But I get it correct on Wolfram

Answer (score 1):

I did the case $a=1$.  The inner integral is
$$
\int_{-\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}} r\;dz = 2r\sqrt{1-r^2}
$$
The next integral is
$$
\int_0^{\cos\theta} 2r\sqrt{1-r^2}\;dr = \frac{2}{3}\left(
1+(\cos^2\theta-1)\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}\right)
$$
In case $\theta > 0$, this simplifies to
$$
\frac{2}{3}\left(1+(\cos^2\theta-1) \sin \theta\right)
$$
But in case $\theta < 0$, it simplifies to
$$
\frac{2}{3}\left(1-(\cos^2\theta-1) \sin \theta\right)
$$
Now it is clear that for the outer integral, $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cdots \;d\theta$
is not equal to $2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cdots\;d\theta$ .

---

This is a good thing to warn calculus students about.  Do not (without thinking) simplify $\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}$ to $\sin \theta$.